# Displaying questions for a quiz using javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I am currently doing the javascriptissexy.com learning path. I am having trouble figuring out the best way to display quiz questions. my question is as a beginner javascript student. How should I tackle the approach of developing the behavior of the quiz app. if you look at my code i have stored my questions in a JSON. So how can I display the questions to a user so he or she can answer the question and interact with the program?

```
var questions = [{

  questions: "What is the name of the biggest part of the human brain?",
  choices : ["cerebrum", "Thalamus","Medulla", "Cerebellum"],
  correstAnswer: 0
},
{
  questions: "The colored part of the human eye that controls how much light passes through the pupil is called the?",
  choices: ["Pupil", "Rods", "Iris", "Cornea"],
  correctAnswer: 2
},
{
  questions: "What is the name of the substance that gives skin and hair its pigment?",
  choices: ["Dermis", "Melanin", "Swear Gland", "Epiderms"],
  correctAnswer: 1
},
 { 
  questions: "The muscles found in the front of your thighs are known as what?",
  choices: ["Adductor", "petella", "tibia", "Quadriceps"],
   correctAnswer: 3
 },
 {
   questions: "15. The shape of DNA is known as?",
   choices: ["Double helix", "Adenine helix", "tri helix", "thymine"],
   correctAnswer: 0
 }, 
 {
   questions: "A structure composed of two or more tissues is termed?",
   choices: ["serous membrane", "complex tissue", "organ system", "organ"],
   correctAnswer: 3
 },
 {
   questions: "The heart is ____ to the lungs?",
   choices: ["superior", "dorsal", "medial", "lateral"],
   correctAnswer: 2
 }, 
  {
    questions: "Male hormones are produced by which of the following?",
    choices: ["prostate", "testes", "vas deferens", "prepuce"],
    correctAnswer: 1
  },
   {
     questions: "Which of the following terms describes the body's ability to maintain its normal state?",
     choices: ["anabolism", "catabolism", "tolerance", "homoestasis"],
     correctAnswer: 3
   }, 
    {
      questions: "Each of the following is known to help prevent infection EXCEPT?",
      choices: ["hair in nose", "mucous membranes", "osteoblasts", "saliva"],
      correctAnswer: 3
    }  ];
/*
 * Question variables
 */
var currentQuestions = 0;
var currentAnswer = 0;
var quizDone = false;


$(document).ready(function(){

/* 
 * Show current question
 */
  displayQuestions();

  function randomize(questions) {
    var currentIndex = questions.length; 
    var tempQuestion, randomIndex;

    //pick remaining element
    while (currentIndex > 1 ) {
      randomIndex = math.floor(math.random() * currentIndex);
     currentIndex -= 1;
     tempQuestion = question[currentIndex];
      questions[currentIndex] = questions[randomIndex];
      questions[randomIndex] = tempQuestion;

    }
    return questions;
  }


});
```

My codepen link is https://codepen.io/OA11an/pen/jVWMEy?editors=0010

Comment: Is there part of the problem that if you had some pointers on you feel you could get moving again?

Comment: Well first I have looked at other resources and I am still understanding what approach to follow after storing my questions in JSON. How do I display the questions? I am still in the beginner/Intermediate phase

Comment: Need to narrow these issues down to one at a time and be more specific about what your problems are related to that issue. Whole question is currently far too broad

Comment: So my question is as a beginner javascript student. How should I tackle the approach of developing the behavior of a quiz app. if you look at my code i have stored my questions in a JSON. So how can I display the questions to a user so he or she can answer the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***I had started writing this before HenryDev's answer, and even though I saw he was finished and the answer was accepted, I figured this would be good information to read regardless***

There's a basic coding philosophy many people use and go by, and with a few different versions. It's called Model-View-Controller (MVC) for short. It tries to help you split your code into distinct chunks so that you do not end up with what many people refer to as "Spaghetti code" (code that is just... just everywhere).

The basics of this, and please everyone before your pitchforks go up these are *my* understandings of MVC as I have picked it up through the years, so if it is not verbatim what *you* would say, don't lynch me for it, is as followed:

### Model

The entire point of a model is to simply and solely be responsible for getting the data. Whether or not the data you are using is quiz questions/answers, random numbers generated on the page, airline info, whatever. the Model of your code is where that is stored.

Each **type** of model in your code should have a different model object / class (depending the language you are using). So in this case you have a `Questions` model, aka the aggregate collection of all of your questions, and what I would say is a `Question` (note, no 's', singular). The `Questions` job is to pull the correct `Question` objects from wherever it is you store them. The approach will vary depending on what system make up you are using (MEAN stack, LAMP stack, insert list of a thousand different applicable stacks you could use). The `Question` job is simply to store the relevant data for **one** question (the question, it's answer choices, the correct answer, etc.)

### View

The view is in charge of taking your data from your Model and doing two things

1. displaying it a way that is logical. This varies *heavily* from case to case. The basic idea I follow is that I wouldn't display a blog post the same way I'd display a navigation menu. It all depends on what you are showing. Before you start with a view my biggest suggestion is to think about what makes sense for this.
2. Linking that up with actions from the **Controller** to modify or change data.

### Controller

The controller is kind of the big boss in all of this, even though it is often listed last. Your controller is the logic machine behind all of your work since the **Model**'s job is simply to get data, and the **View**'s main job is to show that data, the **Controller** is where most of your application logic should go. It decides what Models should be used, and often times *a* (there can be more than one) controller decides what **View** should be shown.

With all of that in mind, here is a basic setup I just did right now. (Quick thing, I used jQuery and Bootstrap to help make it pretty with minimal effort on my part).

```js
$(function() {
    //This notation for jQuery calls a function when the Dom is ready or page has loaded. I can never remember. I use it as a short hand for $(document).ready but I could be totally wrong.

    //Because I read that you are a beginner in javascript, let's just assume that our Questions array a very basic Model.
    //And that each object in the array is a Question model. Once you get some more practice, this should make a lot more sense.
    var Questions = [{

      questions: "What is the name of the biggest part of the human brain?",
      choices: ["Cerebrum", "Thalamus", "Medulla", "Cerebellum"],
      correctAnswer: 0
    }, {
      questions: "The colored part of the human eye that controls how much light passes through the pupil is called the?",
      choices: ["Pupil", "Rods", "Iris", "Cornea"],
      correctAnswer: 2
    }, {
      questions: "What is the name of the substance that gives skin and hair its pigment?",
      choices: ["Dermis", "Melanin", "Swear Gland", "Epiderms"],
      correctAnswer: 1
    }, {
      questions: "The muscles found in the front of your thighs are known as what?",
      choices: ["Adductor", "petella", "tibia", "Quadriceps"],
      correctAnswer: 3
    }, {
      questions: "The shape of DNA is known as?",
      choices: ["Double helix", "Adenine helix", "tri helix", "thymine"],
      correctAnswer: 0
    }, {
      questions: "A structure composed of two or more tissues is termed?",
      choices: ["serous membrane", "complex tissue", "organ system", "organ"],
      correctAnswer: 3
    }, {
      questions: "The heart is ____ to the lungs?",
      choices: ["superior", "dorsal", "medial", "lateral"],
      correctAnswer: 2
    }, {
      questions: "Male hormones are produced by which of the following?",
      choices: ["prostate", "testes", "vas deferens", "prepuce"],
      correctAnswer: 1
    }, {
      questions: "Which of the following terms describes the body's ability to maintain its normal state?",
      choices: ["anabolism", "catabolism", "tolerance", "homoestasis"],
      correctAnswer: 3
    }, {
      questions: "Each of the following is known to help prevent infection EXCEPT?",
      choices: ["hair in nose", "mucous membranes", "osteoblasts", "saliva"],
      correctAnswer: 3
    }]; // end Questions

    //Many people would now use something called Angular, it's a Javascript library which sort of... links together the view/model sections very nicely. Since you are learning, I will leave that out and do it via straight jQuery.

    var question_container = $('#questions-container');
    //Grabs the question container, aka our form.

    question_container.on('submit', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      //Let's just stop the default event.
      var questions = $(this).children('.question');
      //This gets each question
      questions.each(function(i, el) {
        var $el = $(el);
        //I do this as a short hand. by default the element passed down is a simply HTML object, and not a jQuery object. I use this notation to keep from getting myself confused
        var selected = $el.find(':checked');
        //This looks through our HTML to find a child element of the Question element we have that is selected;
        $el.toggleClass('bg-danger', selected.val() != $el.data('answer'));
        //This toggles a class I borrowed from bootstrap, bg-danger, if the value is not equal to our answer
        $el.toggleClass('bg-success', selected.val() == $el.data('answer'));
        //This toggles a success class, bg-success, if the value IS equal to the answer we have stored
      });

    })

    $.each(Questions, function(i, Question) {
      var container = $('<div class="question">'); //Creates a new div with a class of 'question'
      var qHeader = $('<h3>').html(Question.questions); // Creates, and then assigns HTML to , an H3 element that will be the header of our question
      var ul = $('<ul class="list-unstyled">'); //Creates a new list where the answers will be set down, with a class of 'list-unstyled'

      container.data('answer', Question.correctAnswer);
      //This is a jQuery thing that stores the correct answer on the container (div.question) so that we don't have to loop through questions after questions.

      question_container.append(container.append(qHeader));
      //Appends our current container to the form we have up above

      $.each(Question.choices, function(j, Choice) {
        //jQuery function, loops through all the choices in the current question. Notice I used j here instead of I to avoid confusion with the $.each call above
        var item = $('<li> ' + Choice + '</li>'); //Creates a new list item with the text for the answer already inserted
        var radio = $('<input type="radio" name="question[' + i + ']" value="' + j + '" />');
        //Creates a radio button, with a very specific name and value. Check the outcome of the HTML and feel free to fiddle with it if you don't understand why i did what I did here.
        radio.prependTo(item);
        //Prepends the radio element to the li so it appears before the Choice text
        item.appendTo(ul);
        //Adds this li item to our list, created above.
      }); // end $.each(Question.choices);
      ul.appendTo(container);
      //Adds the ul to our container

    }); //end $.each(Questions);

  }) //end $()
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Let's take a Quiz!</h1>
<div class="questions container">
  <form action="your_page_here.php" id="questions-container">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" />
    <input type="reset" class="btn btn-info" />
  </form>
</div>
```

### Edit

Here is a link to the codepen I developed this on, because of the sandboxing for the snippet editor on some browsers the code doesn't seem to work.

[Codepen Here](http://codepen.io/jhechtf/pen/oYxeBQ)

Comment: question_container.on('submit', function(e) {} what does e parameter mean? is it waiting for an event? Also your MVC was very helpful thank you.

Comment: It's adding an event to he form object that fires when the form is submitted. The (e)  is the event object passed to all events it gives you information about it. E.preventDefault() stops the default action of this event (the form submitted and taking the page somewhere else)

Comment: @AllanJulianOloo It doesn't work, HenryDev's answer works. Do you bother to test the answer to see if they work or not?

Comment: How is it not working? It works for me chrome on Windows.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the solution. Hope it helps!

```js
var questions = [{
  
  question: "What is the name of the biggest part of the human brain?",
  choices : ["cerebrum", "Thalamus","Medulla", "Cerebellum"],
  correstAnswer: 0
},
{
  question: "The colored part of the human eye that controls how much light passes through the pupil is called the?",
  choices: ["Pupil", "Rods", "Iris", "Cornea"],
  correctAnswer: 2
},
{
  question: "What is the name of the substance that gives skin and hair its pigment?",
  choices: ["Dermis", "Melanin", "Swear Gland", "Epiderms"],
  correctAnswer: 1
},
 { 
  question: "The muscles found in the front of your thighs are known as what?",
  choices: ["Adductor", "petella", "tibia", "Quadriceps"],
   correctAnswer: 3
 },
 {
   question: "15. The shape of DNA is known as?",
   choices: ["Double helix", "Adenine helix", "tri helix", "thymine"],
   correctAnswer: 0
 }, 
 {
   question: "A structure composed of two or more tissues is termed?",
   choices: ["serous membrane", "complex tissue", "organ system", "organ"],
   correctAnswer: 3
 },
 {
   question: "The heart is ____ to the lungs?",
   choices: ["superior", "dorsal", "medial", "lateral"],
   correctAnswer: 2
 }, 
  {
    question: "Male hormones are produced by which of the following?",
    choices: ["prostate", "testes", "vas deferens", "prepuce"],
    correctAnswer: 1
  },
   {
     question: "Which of the following terms describes the body's ability to maintain its normal state?",
     choices: ["anabolism", "catabolism", "tolerance", "homoestasis"],
     correctAnswer: 3
   }, 
    {
      question: "Each of the following is known to help prevent infection EXCEPT?",
      choices: ["hair in nose", "mucous membranes", "osteoblasts", "saliva"],
      correctAnswer: 3
    }  ];

$(document).ready(function(){
  
  var questionCounter = 0; //Tracks question number
  var selections = []; //Array containing user choices
  var quiz = $('#quiz'); //Quiz div object
  
  // Display initial question
  displayNext();
  
  // Click handler for the 'next' button
  $('#next').on('click', function () {
    
    // Suspend click listener during fade animation
    if(quiz.is(':animated')) {        
      return false;
    }
    choose();
    
    // If no user selection, progress is stopped
    if (isNaN(selections[questionCounter])) {
      alert('Please make a selection!');
    } else {
      questionCounter++;
      displayNext();
    }
    return false;
  });
  
  // Click handler for the 'prev' button
  $('#prev').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    if(quiz.is(':animated')) {
      return false;
    }
    choose();
    questionCounter--;
    displayNext();
  });
  
  // Click handler for the 'Start Over' button
  $('#start').on('click', function () {
    if(quiz.is(':animated')) {
      return false;
    }
    questionCounter = 0;
    selections = [];
    displayNext();
    $('#start').hide();
    return false;
  });
  
  // Creates and returns the div that contains the questions and 
  // the answer selections
  function createQuestionElement(index) {
    var qElement = $('<div>', {
      id: 'question'
    });
    
    var header = $('<h3>Question ' + (index + 1) + ':</h3>');
    qElement.append(header);
    
    var question = $('<p>').append(questions[index].question);
    qElement.append(question);
    
    var radioButtons = createRadios(index);
    qElement.append(radioButtons);
    
    return qElement;
  }
  
  // Creates a list of the answer choices as radio inputs
  function createRadios(index) {
    var radioList = $('<ul>');
    var item;
    var input = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < questions[index].choices.length; i++) {
      item = $('<li>');
      input = '<input type="radio" name="answer" value=' + i + ' />';
      input += questions[index].choices[i];
      item.append(input);
      radioList.append(item);
    }
    return radioList;
  }
  
  // Reads the user selection and pushes the value to an array
  function choose() {
    selections[questionCounter] = +$('input[name="answer"]:checked').val();
  }
  
  // Displays next requested element
  function displayNext() {
    quiz.fadeOut(function() {
      $('#question').remove();
      
      if(questionCounter < questions.length){
        var nextQuestion = createQuestionElement(questionCounter);
        quiz.append(nextQuestion).fadeIn();
        if (!(isNaN(selections[questionCounter]))) {
          $('input[value='+selections[questionCounter]+']').prop('checked', true);
        }
        
        // Controls display of 'prev' button
        if(questionCounter === 1){
          $('#prev').show();
        } else if(questionCounter === 0){
          
          $('#prev').hide();
          $('#next').show();
        }
      }else {
        var scoreElem = displayScore();
        quiz.append(scoreElem).fadeIn();
        $('#next').hide();
        $('#prev').hide();
        $('#start').show();
      }
    });
  }
  
  function displayScore() {
    var score = $('<p>',{id: 'question'});
    
    var numCorrect = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < selections.length; i++) {
      if (selections[i] === questions[i].correctAnswer) {
        numCorrect++;
      }
    }
    
    score.append('You got ' + numCorrect + ' questions out of ' +
                 questions.length + ' right!');
    return score;
  }
  
});
```

```css
body {
  background-image: url(http://7te.org/images/570x363/anatomyhuman-anatomy-human-1280x800-wallpaper-body-wallpaper-76530.jpg);
}
a{
  text-decoration: none;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 45px;
  font-family: cursive;
  color: teal;
 text-shadow: 2px 1px black;

  
}
ul {
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
}

li {
 list-style: none;
}

.radiochoices{
  font-family: comic sans ms;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
} 

#container {
    margin:auto;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 0px 0px 30px 0px;
    background-color: #1E90FF;
    border:4px solid #B0E0E6;
    border-radius: 13px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-weight: bold;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #888;
}

.center {
  margin: 205px 40px 0px 245px
}
.reset {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='container'>
      <div id='title'>
        <h1 class="title"> Human Anatomy Questions </h1>
      </div>
        <br/>
        <div id='quiz'></div>
        <button class="btn btn-info btn-large" id='next'><a href='#'>Next</a></button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning btn-large reset" id='prev'><a href='#'>Prev</a></button>
        <button class="btn btn-info btn-large" id='start'> <a href='#'>Start Over</a></button>
      </div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes it does. Why did you have   displayNext(); at the top of the page before it was written? I don't understand that part.

Comment: if(quiz.is (':animated')) {
    return false;
  }  what is this code doing? Also why are you calling chose() underneath it when you have it defined later in the code?

Comment: Hello u have taken the questions variable and ur writing the validations and clickable events in js but without taking that variable can we call json file and dispalay the data? Pls clarify my doubt

Answer (score 1):

I also had fun playing with this and making it functional. Thanks for the motivation. Here is what I did:

- I corrected the typo `correstAnswer` in one of the questions.
- I corrected the field name `questions` to `question`.
- I added the `.correct` and `.wrong` CSS classes.
- I completely rewrote the JavaScript code, keeping it as simple as possible.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eBZEEe?editors=1111

What's left to do:

- Shuffle the answers, so that the quizzers actually learn the answers, not their position.

Comment: That is really nicely laid out, I have got to give it to you.